# arm-none-eabi-gcc 4.8 segmentation fault (ChibiOS-RT)

Tags: c, gcc, arm

When compiling a ChibiOS-RT project, I get the following error at link time (with arm-none-eabi-gcc 4.8):

```
../../../../test/rt/test.c: In function 'TestThread':
../../../../test/rt/test.c:314:7: internal compiler error: Segmentation fault: 11
 msg_t TestThread(void *p) {
   ^
libbacktrace could not find executable to open
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <http://gcc.gnu.org/bugs.html> for instructions.
lto-wrapper: arm-none-eabi-gcc returned 1 exit status
/usr/gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_8-2013q4/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.8.3/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: lto-wrapper failed
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [build/ch.elf] Error 1
```

This does NOT occur with arm-none-eabi-gcc 4.7.

This is one of the OS build files, so I don't want to mess with it -- and I've never seen gcc itself encounter a segmentation fault while building. Additionally, it occurs when building any of project, even ones entirely unchanged from the root ChibiOS repository.

Any advice on diagnosing this problem?

Comment: First, does this happen *every single time* you link this particular thing with this compiler?  If not, what you have is bad RAM.  Second, try wiping out and reinstalling arm-none-eabi-gcc-4.8 *and* whatever version of binutils this is.  If neither of those addresses the problem, you have found an honest-to-Ghod bug in the compiler and/or linker, and you should consult `gcc-help@gcc.gnu.org` for advice on how to report it.

Comment: An ICE is a bug; GCC itself recognized that something is wrong.  If it worked OK with 4.7, go back to 4.7, and use it to build 4.8 or 4.9.  'Tis odd; normally, GCC gets a good workout building itself and its support libraries.

Answer (score 4):

GCC 4.8 does not support `LTO` and `ggdb` enabled together. Just disable one or another.

Try to configure your Makefile:

```
USE_LTO = no
```

or

```
USE_OPT = -O2 -fomit-frame-pointer -falign-functions=16
```

without -ggdb flag